# Clipping NSString based on length + range of string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a large NSString that I would like to trim:

```
this is an example of my long string
```

First I trim it to a certain word or words. For example, I pick the word "long". To achieve this:

```
NSRange textRange = [[theEntireString lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"long"];
NSString *subString = //do something to get the individual word(s)??
```

Which would result in:

```
long
```

However, I need 10 characters in my final result. So in this case the final result I want to achieve is:

```
my long st
```

As you can see, I evenly add characters on the left and right side of the word until I reach the desired character count, placing the word or words in the middle.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to post the code that you already have.

Comment: In this case, I disagree with H2CO3, though it's always best to have exactly what you have tried and what is wrong with your solution. I can see here that you're not just asking "Code please?!" and have actually made a start on a solution.

It's also quite a small problem, you're not asking for an entire program.

It should also be noted, that this is the reason why I didn't provide a complete solution, rather just one that fits your exact case over a general solution. I hope that you can extend the code I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the string doesn't contain the defined separator more than once, this should see you right:

```
NSString *string = @"This is an example of my LONG string.";

NSString *separator = @"long";

NSInteger desiredLength = 10;

NSRange range = [[string lowercaseString] rangeOfString:separator];

if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSInteger remainder = (desiredLength - [separator length]);

    NSInteger halfRemainder = (remainder / 2);

    range = NSMakeRange((range.location - halfRemainder), (range.length + remainder));

    NSString *result = [string substringWithRange:range];

    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
}
```

`result: my LONG st`

This should be fairly customisable to suit your needs.

Also, it might be worth checking the halfRemainder isn't trying to divide an odd number (i.e. 5 / 2) as this is cast to an integer which may cause isses with out of range exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't account for strings such as the following, but it should get you started.

"long string" - No characters at start"

"string is long" - No characters at end

"This is a long long string" - double find for query string

"long" - less than 10 characters

"No instance of loong" - No instances of the search string.

```
NSString *s = @"this is an example of my long string";
NSString *searchString = @"long";
NSRange range = [[s lowercaseString] rangeOfString:searchString];

range.location -= (10 - (searchString.length)) / 2;
range.length = 10;

NSLog(@"%@", [s substringWithRange:range]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *theEntireString = @"afsfaof";

NSRange textRange = [[theEntireString lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"long"];
if (textRange.length < 10) {
    NSRange finalRange = NSMakeRange((10-textRange.length)/2, 10);
}else{
    NSString *subString = [theEntireString substringWithRange:textRange];
}
```